# Closure Factory, with internal functions calling other internal functions

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, factory

So I have an external API that I have no control over. The API used to create some workflow 
of other part of the program, to create that workflow the user- in this case me, have to define a closure that

1. `state` Object.
2. define an `entrypoint` function, which calls the method that `initiate` the workflow,  provided by the API
3. the  `initiate` method take a function, say `func1` as an argument, here the actual workflow starts
4. `func1` awaits some event then it updates the `state` and returns a function that returns `func2` which is the second step in the workflow, and you read it right it with two returns `(input: stepInput) => func2(input, state)`

and I have around 20 of these workflows, with average 5 steps for the single workflow and even the **options used to tweak the event are similar with minor changes, there are only two variations of events**.

```
async function Workflow() {
        interface State {
            title: string;
            step: number;
            totalSteps: number;
            result1: string;
            result2: string;
            result3: string;
        }

        async function entrypoint() {
            const state = {} as Partial<State>;
            await initiate(input => step1(input, state));
            return state as State;
        }

        const title = 'workflow title';

        async function step1(input: StepInput, state: Partial<State>) {
            const result1 = await event1({ // options that tweaks the event });


            state.result1 = result1;
            return (input: StepInput) => step2(input, state);
        }
        async function step2(input: StepInput, state: Partial<State>) {
            const result2 = await event1({ // options that tweaks the event });
            state.result2 = result2;
            return (input: StepInput) => step3(input, state);
        }
        async function step3(input: StepInput, state: Partial<State>) {
            const result3 = await event2({ // options that tweaks the event });
            state.result3 = result3;
        }

        state = await entrypoint();
}
```

I tried to Implement a workflow factory, I ran out of ideas what to pass this factory but I think it will look something like that

```
async function WorkflowFactory(
    steps: any[], // still have no clue what this should be
    ) {
    // the workflow 
    return async function() {

        function someFuncion() {
            // probably here the factory magic will happen
        }

        async function entrypoint() {
            const state = { } as Partial<State>;
            await initiate(input => steps[0](input, state) );
        }
    };
}
```

I don't know for sure if this is the right architectural approach, **even a suggestion for different pattern is appreciated**

Comment: You can use a register mechanism to add the steps, and then when init is called, execute them one by one.

My implementation in `global-store` may be helpful to you.

Comment: I have something close to this, but as stated in the question I want to remove the redundancy in workflow they are awfully similar with minor changes